# confused about Quick Sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

Currently I am learning quick sort. I've followed the quick sort rules; but I have found a strange thing.

The process is just like this picture.

Please help me find where I am fault:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  static void QuickSortFromMiddle(int[] arr, int low, int high)
    {

        if (low < high)
        {
            int middleValue = arr[(low+high)/2];
            int h = high+1;
            int l = low-1;
            while (l < h)
            {
                while (arr[--h] > middleValue && l<h);

                while (arr[++l] < middleValue && l<h) ;

                if (l >= h)
                    break; 
                int temp = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[h];
                arr[h] = temp;

            }

            QuickSortFromMiddle(arr,low,l-1);
            QuickSortFromMiddle(arr, h+1, high);
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    static void QuickSort(int[] arr)
    {
        QuickSortFromMiddle(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    static void TestQuickSort()
    {

        var arr = new[] { 1, 5, 3, 4, 57, 5, 5, 53 };
        QuickSort(arr);
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

Here is result (I am so confused....)

[image]

as  Dukeling said "The pivot is typically moved to either end"

Firstly, I should put the pivot at the end of the array

Secondly,I should put the pivot in the right position of arr(greater than left,and less than right)

here is right process:

[image]

Comment: Have you run it line by line in a debugger to see what it does and see why it’s doing something wrong?

Comment: yes  I try;
the original arr: 1, 5, 3, 4, 57, 5, 5, 53 
after the first,the result: 1, 4, 3, 5, 57, 5, 5, 53  (just like pic)

Comment: Try this [quick sort visualizer](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/quick-sort/visualize/) to understand how it should work and then compare it with a debugger session of your own code by watching it step by step.

Comment: wow~ that is good article, I will see it,then debug it, thanks a lot~

Comment: The pivot is typically moved to either end to avoid the added complexity of having to cater specifically for it or move it around a bunch. In your example, you'd need to swap 3 and 4 as well.

Comment: Thanks Oliver I find a good quick sort visualizer ,learn code and I optimize,
do you think it is right? code is here

 if ( A[ j ] <= piv) {
                if(j==i){
                          // there is no need to swap
                }
                else{
                       swap (A[ i ],A [ j ]);
                  }
                
            i += 1;
        }
@Oliver

Comment: Thanks Dukeling, your advice is key point to resolve this problem~

Answer (score 1):

The overall algorithm is as follows:

1. Pick an element, called a pivot, from the array.
2. Partitioning: reorder the array so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater than the pivot come after it (equal values can go either way). After this partitioning, the pivot is in its final position. This is called the partition operation.
3. Recursively apply the above steps to the sub-array of elements with smaller values and separately to the sub-array of elements with greater values.

There are several schemes for partitioning, any of which would work, as long as the condition is satisfied. Your partitioning scheme is something i've never seen before. In particular, I've never seen a quick sort partitioning scheme that takes the centrally located value as the pivot.
Please see [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for some standard partitioning schemes (Eg Lomuto).

Overall, your partition scheme makes the following limitations:

1. It assumes that the central element (in terms of position) is the median.
2. It does not allow arbitrary positioning of elements less than or greater to the median. For example, before swapping `arr[l]` and `arr[h]`, you don't even check whether they need to be swapped. You just assume that after the initial moving of `l` and `h` (the two inner while loops), all other numbers need to be swapped.

You need to make your partition scheme more generic, maybe try understanding and using one of the standard ones.

Comment: Thanks Parakram Majumdar~

 In my opinion, there is nothing to do with "takes the centrally located value as the pivot"

We can chose any value of  array as pivot; but we should put pivot at end of array or first, I give the right process (you can see the question ,I have given the right process)

Answer (score 1):

As Parakram wrote, the pivotelement is you main problem.
The algorithm does not split you array in the middle or at the position of the pivotelement, it splits the array into two with the pivot-*value* between. The position where it will be split is searched by l and h. When they meet, you got the position to split.

I put some comments in your code. This one is working, i think..

```
    static void QuickSortFromMiddle(int[] arr, int low, int high)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Low: {0}, High: {1}, Arr: {2}", low, high, string.Join("|", arr));
        if (low < high)
        {
            int pivot = arr[high]; // Select you pivot element. After the run all smaller numbers will be left of it, all bigger ones on the high-side.
            int h = high;
            int l = low;

            // breaks at specific condition within the loop
            while(true)
            {
                // Search for the first element which is smaller, beginning on the high-side
                while (arr[h] >= pivot && l < h)
                {
                    h--;
                }

                // Search for the first element which is bigger, beginning on the low-side
                while (arr[l] < pivot && l < h)
                {
                    l++;
                }

                // we now have pivot (still at position "high")
                // we got an element which is bigger that pivot on "l"
                // we got an element which is smaller than pivot on "h"
                // conclusion: we need to change their positions

                Console.WriteLine("h: " + h + ", l: " + l +  ", Arr: " + string.Join("|", arr));

                // if l&h are at the same position, we're done and have to check if the pivot element has to be moved to this position
                if (l >= h)
                    break;

                // we change elements on position l and h, because we know that arr[l] is bigger that our pivot and arr[h] is smaller.
                int temp = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[h];
                arr[h] = temp;

            }

            // l equals h. This is now the position for pivot, because all elements on the lower side are smaller and all elements on the right side are bigger
            Console.WriteLine(">h: " + h + ", l: " + l + ", Arr: " + string.Join("|", arr));
            if (arr[l] > pivot)
            {
                arr[high] = arr[l];
                arr[l] = pivot;
            }

            // We start two new runs. One for the lower values: from Low to l and from l+1 to high.
            // Why? As we know l is our pivot value which splits the elements into two groups. smaller ones on the lower side, bigger ones on the higher side.
            // We now can focus on those two groups separately.
            QuickSortFromMiddle(arr, low, l);
            QuickSortFromMiddle(arr, l + 1, high);
        }

    }
```

Comment: kara ,I find you have cool hair style( I can't image you are a programmer); thanks your test code and advice; after deep thinking, I put the right process in my question ,you can see it~